# `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when using Google as the signin provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have seen many posts for this error and all of them said to add my URL under both the **API key** that's generated by Firebase and the **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**.

[image]

My domain is `lyricsandquotes.org` so I added the URL in both of these.
The screenshot from the API Key:
[image: The screenshot from the API Key]

The screenshot from the OAuth:
[image: The screenshot from the OAuth]

However, I am still getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometime it takes some time to work after adding the links. Wait for some hour and then try.

Comment: I waited and it still doesn't work. Did I add all the right links? Is there another place where I need to add those links?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I had to change the redirect URI under the Client ID credentials to the one specified in the error message:
[image]